# Split string into array with regex but without removing the matches

Tags: crystal-lang

In python I can do:

```
import re

re.split('(o)', 'hello world')
```

and get:

```
['hell', 'o', ' w', 'o', 'rld']
```

---

With crystal:

```
"hello world".split(/(o)/)
```

I get:

```
["hell", " w", "rld"]
```

But I want to keep the matches in the array like in the python example. Is it possible?

http://crystal-lang.org/api/String.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just got added, see [this issue](https://github.com/manastech/crystal/issues/772).

Until that lands in a release you can trick with lookaround expressions:

```rb
"hello world".split(/(?<=o)|(?=o)/) #=> ["hell", "o", " w", "o", "rld"]
```

Comment: Wow I'm a complete scrooloose, you can even tell I read the thread because of the pr. Can't believe I forgot about that and wasted time trying to work around it. :| But the lookaround also works, thanks again.

Comment: Just realised, this question has come full circle. SO tag was created from a thread about this question. SO gets the very same question...

Comment: Yes, noticed that too :D